# Creating Proper Django Paths

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Each group needs its own url in order to view, however, my understanding of constructing URL paths seems incomplete. What I currently have for each path containing "slug" does not work. I am attempting to make the final URL look along the lines of ".../groups/posts/in/group_name".

urls.py

```
app_name = 'groups'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ListGroups.as_view(), name='all'),
    path('new/', views.CreateGroup.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('posts/in/<slug:groups>', views.SingleGroup.as_view(), name='single'),
    path('join/<slug>', views.JoinGroup.as_view(), name='join'),
    path('leave/<slug>', views.LeaveGroup.as_view(), name='join'),
]
```

views.py

```
from .models import Group, GroupMember

# Create your views here.
class CreateGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    fields = ['name', 'description']
    model = Group

class SingleGroup(generic.DetailView):
    model = Group

class ListGroups(generic.ListView):
    model = Group

class JoinGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug':self.kwargs.get('slug')})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = get_object_or_404(Group, slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        try:
            GroupMember.objects.create(user=self.request.user, group=group)
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.warning(request, 'You are a already a member')
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'You are now a member')

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

class LeaveGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug':self.kwargs.get('slug')})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            membership = GroupMember.objects.filter(
            user=self.request.user,
            group__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')
            ).get()
        except GroupMember.DoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(request, 'You are not in this group')
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully left this group')

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

models.py

```
User = get_user_model()
register = template.Library()

# Create your models here.
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    description_html = models.TextField(editable=False, default='', blank=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='GroupMember')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.description = misaka.html(self.description)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='memberships', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_groups', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('group', 'user')
```

I've obfuscated most of the imports that I have on the actual script.

Answer (score 1):

I've spotted several issues in your code. In your `urlpatterns` there are two paths with same name, `join`:

```
...
path('join/<slug>', views.JoinGroup.as_view(), name='join'), 
path('leave/<slug>', views.LeaveGroup.as_view(), name='join'), #name='leave' probably
...
```

When named urlpatterns clash, URL that reverse finds, depends on whichever pattern is last in your project's urlpatterns list. See more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

Then, when you use `reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})` you should pass in kwargs not `slug` but `groups` as this is the name of the argument. i.e. definition `.../<slug:groups>` shoud be read as `groups` which are of type `slug`. So your reverse should like this:

```
reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'groups':self.slug})
```

In urlpatterns where you do not have named url arguments, you should be using `reverse` with `args` argument:

```
reverse('groups:join', args = [self.slug])
```